# How to retrieve the thumbnail for an Instagram TV (IGTV) video without a reviewed Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instaloader

I am writing a Python script using instaloader to assemble a list of thumbnails for all posts of an Instagram profile. For regular posts, this can be easily done by appending `/media` to the post URL, e.g.:

```
> https://www.instagram.com/p/CP0-foultIJ/
< https://www.instagram.com/p/CP0-foultIJ/media?size=l
```

But then I stumbled upon some IGTV contents of the same profile, for instance:

```
> https://www.instagram.com/tv/COH2xEjIpp7
```

Unfortunately, `https://www.instagram.com/tv/COH2xEjIpp7/media` does not exist (error 404). Is there any other way to retrieve the thumbnail for an IGTV video?

I am aware of Instagram's [oEmbed feature](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/oembed_read), but Facebook has changed the requirements for this feature recently and they now require the "successful completion of the App Review process" before you can use these endpoints. Since my script will only be used internally, I cannot submit our app for review.

Comment: Instagram doesn't allow you to interact with them if you don't use the API. And yes you can complete the App Review Process even if it is just an internal app.

Comment: > And yes you can complete the App Review Process even if it is just an internal app.
/
How should I? In their [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review/before-you-submit) they say: *Make sure we can access your app or website. Your app must be publicly available or you must provide instructions on how to access it."